# Why are my Wii Remotes being laggy and choppy?

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, nintendo-wii, wii-u, wiimote

So I'm playing Super Smash Bros for Wii U (offline) and the controls are doing all sorts of weird things.  Sometimes there's just crazy lag (like I'll hold left to run and it takes like 2 seconds for them to start running) and sometimes everything is just crazy choppy, for example I'll hold left to run and the character will run then stop then run then stop, etc, despite me not letting go of the control stick.  Re-synching doesn't work.  The thing that makes me the most confused is that it only happens sometimes and it works fine on my dad's Wii U but not mine. All my Wii remotes do it.  Also the cursor is super choppy too when you are pointing at the screen.  I've read that the Gamepad can interfere with the remotes but my Gamepad has been in the same place since I bought the Wii U and this problem has only just started.  Also this problem happens with more games than just Smash Bros.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Configure your TV to be in 'Game mode'

Comment: If it only affects your console and not your father's, all I can think of is interference. There's probably something between your Wii U and Wiimotes that's degrading the connection between the two. Either that, or your Wii U is in need of repairs. Things to look out for: walls, metallic objects, objects that produce waves (wireless phones, microwave ovens, etc.), objects with lots of water (people & animals, large quantities of water bottles, etc.), great distance.

Comment: My gaming set up has not changed in over 2 years and this problem is only now starting to happen.  There's nothing between my Wiimotes and Wii U either.  That's why I'm so confused.  Nothings changed but suddenly there's a problem. Thanks for helping though I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure about *all* the choppy controls - But for pointing; ensure that the sensor bar is properly placed, and be aware of any reflective surfaces (like glass) between the sensor bar and the wii-mote. In the past I've had trouble with a glass coffee table between the Wii-motes and TV, as well as one time where the sensor bar slid back a touch and the remotes were catching both the sensor bar and a reflection of the sensor bar off the shiny top of the TV. Also, I've had some issues with the Wii-motes thinking light-bulbs were part of the sensor bar...

Comment: Hmmm well It is on top of a glass TV stand...but it has been for months now.  Not sure why it'd suddenly stop working.  Thanks for the advice though! I'll move some things around and try to make the Wiimotes happy.

Comment: ...have you changed the batteries?